# Extract and Write CSV file only for HTML Tables containing a certain word with Beautiful Soup and Python

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have an html file that contains several tables. I want to extract only the tables that contain `Crtf NoCrtf` somewhere in the table. I am able to get all the tables with

`soup.find_all('table')`

but I do not need every table, just the tables containing the previously mentioned 'Crtf NoCrtf'. I am brand new to python and Beautiful Soup, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you supply a URL for the file?

Comment: It is a downloaded file. Do you have an email I can send it to?

Comment: Better to put it on a publich sharing site so multiple people can try

Comment: Let me make sure the document does not contain any information that is not publicly available. I am walking into a class so it may take me a little while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

[csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

not sure what you mean by contain crtf nocrtf, but if you mean the text then:

```
tables = soup.find_all('table')
for table in tables:
    if 'Crtf NoCrtf' in table.get_text():
        {{ "code for writing to csv" }}
```

if you mean the class is 'Crtf NoCrtf' then:

```
tables = soup.find_all('table', {'class': 'Crtf NoCrtf'})
for table in tables:
    {{ "code for writing to csv" }}
```

Using the [csv library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) from python you can write the data to the csv in whatever format you want.